# Question about template's value_type usage in Stroustrup's book example

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, generic-programming

In Stroustrup's "A Tour of C++" there is a code snippet

```
template<typename C>
using Value_type = typename C::value_type;  // the type of C’s elements

template<typename Container>
void algo(Container& c)
{
    /* (1) */ 
    Vector<Value_type<Container>> vec;  // keep results here
    // ...
}
```

Why we need this `using`, how it differs from writing in `(1)` just

```
Vector<Container::value_type> vec;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is this declaration:

```
Vector<Container::value_type> vec;
```

is not actually valid, and is an error. Instead you need to write:

```
Vector<typename Container::value_type> vec;
```

which is more verbose.

The purpose of the alias template `Value_type` is to make it more convenient to use a member type alias of `Container` without having to say `typename` each time.